# asp.net mvc send email error: unable to send an email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email

I have mvc web app sending an email when new user gets created with following code:

```
private static void SendMail(User user)
        {
            string ActivationLink = "http://localhost/Account/Activate/" +
                                     user.UserName + "/" + user.NewEmailKey;

            var message = new MailMessage("ashu@gmail.com", user.Email)
            {
                Subject = "Activate your account",
                Body = ActivationLink
            };

            var client = new SmtpClient("localhost");
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Send(message);
        }
```

What's wrong with my code please tell me.

> ERROR : Failure sending mail. {"Unable to connect to the remote server"}

Smtp configuration :
[image]

Comment: what errors do you get? how is your stmp server configured?

Comment: Please include exception details

Comment: ERROR : Failure sending mail.
{"Unable to connect to the remote server"}

Comment: do you have the SMTP service installed and started on the localhost / dev machine?

Comment: yes all sets i have edit my question with smtp config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the likely causes of this error:

1 You are not supplying the correct authentication details

2 The port is blocked, for example by a firewall

In your example, I notice you are not specifying the port when you create your `SmtpClient` - it may help to specify it.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail opens in port 587, and u need to enable ssl.

Try following code.

```
        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(<fromAddress>, <fromPassword>)
        };
        using (var message = new MailMessage(<fromAddress>, <toAddress>)
        {
            Subject = <subject>,
            Body = <body>
        })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
```